DatFilesLoaderAsyncRunner hangs on Docker container startup resulting in timeout
On my 10.2 site running in Docker, I can see my CM and CD containers starting up and running, however, they seem to hang on the DatFilesLoaderAsyncRunner, specifically near a Resource merger step:
336 10:05:14 WARN  The "SessionExpirationThreadCount" setting contains an invalid value. The default value is used instead. Invalid value: "". Default value: "2"
3624 10:05:14 WARN  Runner started: DatFilesLoaderAsyncRunner
2340 10:05:15 INFO  HttpModule is being initialized
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Cache created: 'DeviceItemsCache' (max size: unrestricted)
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Cache created: 'master[data]' (max size: unrestricted)
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Cache created: 'master[items]' (max size: unrestricted)
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Cache created: 'master[paths]' (max size: unrestricted)
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Cache created: 'master[standardValues]' (max size: unrestricted)
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Cache created: 'master[languageFallbackObsolete]' (max size: unrestricted)
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Cache created: 'master[languageFallback]' (max size: unrestricted)
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Cache created: 'master[isLanguageFallbackValid]' (max size: unrestricted)
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Cache created: 'master[isLanguageFallbackValidObsolete]' (max size: unrestricted)
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Cache created: 'master[itempaths]' (max size: unrestricted)
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Cache created: 'master[blobIDs]' (max size: unrestricted)
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Resource merger: file C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\APP_DATA\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.HORIZON.MASTER.DAT, updated item definitions count = 0.
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Resource merger: file C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\APP_DATA\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.HORIZON.MASTER.DAT, new item definitions count = 5.
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Resource merger: file C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\APP_DATA\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.HORIZON.MASTER.DAT, updated shared definitions count = 0.
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Resource merger: file C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\APP_DATA\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.HORIZON.MASTER.DAT, new shared definitions count = 5.
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Resource merger: file C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\APP_DATA\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.HORIZON.MASTER.DAT, updated language definitions count = 0.
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Resource merger: file C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\APP_DATA\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.HORIZON.MASTER.DAT, new language definitions count = 5.
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Resource merger: file C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\APP_DATA\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.MASTER.DAT, updated item definitions count = 0.
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Resource merger: file C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\APP_DATA\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.MASTER.DAT, new item definitions count = 2462.
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Resource merger: file C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\APP_DATA\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.MASTER.DAT, updated shared definitions count = 0.
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Resource merger: file C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\APP_DATA\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.MASTER.DAT, new shared definitions count = 2462.
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Resource merger: file C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\APP_DATA\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.MASTER.DAT, updated language definitions count = 0.
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Resource merger: file C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\APP_DATA\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.MASTER.DAT, new language definitions count = 2462.
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Resource merger: file C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\APP_DATA\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.MASTER.SPE.DAT, updated item definitions count = 0.
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Resource merger: file C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\APP_DATA\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.MASTER.SPE.DAT, new item definitions count = 691.
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Resource merger: file C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\APP_DATA\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.MASTER.SPE.DAT, updated shared definitions count = 0.
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Resource merger: file C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\APP_DATA\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.MASTER.SPE.DAT, new shared definitions count = 514.
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Resource merger: file C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\APP_DATA\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.MASTER.SPE.DAT, updated language definitions count = 0.
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Resource merger: file C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\APP_DATA\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.MASTER.SPE.DAT, new language definitions count = 691.
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Resource merger: file C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\SITECORE MODULES\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.MASTER.JSS.DAT, updated item definitions count = 0.
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Resource merger: file C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\SITECORE MODULES\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.MASTER.JSS.DAT, new item definitions count = 50.
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Resource merger: file C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\SITECORE MODULES\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.MASTER.JSS.DAT, updated shared definitions count = 0.
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Resource merger: file C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\SITECORE MODULES\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.MASTER.JSS.DAT, new shared definitions count = 50.
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Resource merger: file C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\SITECORE MODULES\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.MASTER.JSS.DAT, updated language definitions count = 0.
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Resource merger: file C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\SITECORE MODULES\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.MASTER.JSS.DAT, new language definitions count = 50.
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Resource merger: file C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\SITECORE MODULES\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.MASTER.LS.DAT, updated item definitions count = 0.
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Resource merger: file C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\SITECORE MODULES\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.MASTER.LS.DAT, new item definitions count = 42.
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Resource merger: file C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\SITECORE MODULES\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.MASTER.LS.DAT, updated shared definitions count = 0.
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Resource merger: file C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\SITECORE MODULES\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.MASTER.LS.DAT, new shared definitions count = 42.
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Resource merger: file C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\SITECORE MODULES\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.MASTER.LS.DAT, updated language definitions count = 0.
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Resource merger: file C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\SITECORE MODULES\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.MASTER.LS.DAT, new language definitions count = 42.
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Resource merger: file C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\SITECORE MODULES\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.MASTER.SXA.DAT, updated item definitions count = 42.
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Resource merger: file C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\SITECORE MODULES\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.MASTER.SXA.DAT, new item definitions count = 7105.
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Resource merger: file C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\SITECORE MODULES\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.MASTER.SXA.DAT, updated shared definitions count = 39.
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Resource merger: file C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\SITECORE MODULES\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.MASTER.SXA.DAT, new shared definitions count = 6109.
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Resource merger: file C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\SITECORE MODULES\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.MASTER.SXA.DAT, updated language definitions count = 42.
2340 10:05:15 INFO  Resource merger: file C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\SITECORE MODULES\ITEMS\MASTER\ITEMS.MASTER.SXA.DAT, new language definitions count = 7105.

Nothing else ever appears after the above logs, except for this when I restart the container:
3756 10:30:22 INFO  **************************************************
3756 10:30:22 WARN  Sitecore shutting down
3756 10:30:22 WARN  Shutdown message: Initialization Error
HostingEnvironment initiated shutdown

As a result, the containers are marked as having been started (but not healthy), as evidenced by the fact that the health check is hanging. When I execute the health check manually in the containers (by running curl http://127.0.0.1/healthz/ready), it hangs indefinitely.
After a good amount of time, the docker compose up command shows the error:
C:\projects\ACME\up.ps1 : Timeout waiting for Sitecore CM to become available via Traefik proxy. Check CM container logs.
At C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1:3 char:7
+       .\up.ps1
+       ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,up.ps1

How can I troubleshoot this?

This scenario can occur when your containers are unable to connect to the SQL server on your host machine.
Fix 1) Set Windows Network to Private
Run docker compose down.
Ensure that the network profile on your host machine is set to private (as opposed to public). You can do this via the Windows GUI, or via the PS command Set-NetConnectionProfile -NetworkCategory Private.
Open SQL Server Configuration Manager and ensure that your SQL network configuration has TCP/IP enabled.

Restart all SQL services, or better yet, restart your PC.
Run docker compose build --no-cache.
Start your containers.
Fix 2) Start the SQL Service
This can also happen if your SQL Server service is not started. Start it. It's also a good idea to rebuild your containers now that the service is started: docker compose build --no-cache.
Also, if your containers are set to start on Windows login, set the SQL Service to "Automatic" instead of "Automatic (Delayed Start)".

